# 'Master-Detail' type query, defaulting 'Detail' values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to query a pre-existing data model with a master-detail type structure, which looks like this:

```
Master
-----
MasterId (PK)
Description


Detail
-----
DetailId (PK)
MasterId (FK)
DetailCategoryId (FK)    
Description
```

There are also a series of Detail records with a MasterId of -1 which indicate default values for each detail category.  So, if for a specified category the Master does not have a Detail, the default value should be retreived.

I've managed to do this for a given master record in a couple of different ways, but the solutions I've came up with so far generally require me, to figure the 'specified' details then union with a set of the missing defaults.

My question is how do I go about doing this for all/multiple Master records?

(This is an existing data model which I am querying for reporting purposes.  I may be able to make minor amendments, but no chance of a full redesign hence the question is really 'how do I deal with this?' rather than 'how do I re-model this?')

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work. You'd just replace the 15 with whatever category.

```
SELECT
    m.MasterId,ISNULL(d.DetailId,dflt.DetailId)
FROM Master m
LEFT JOIN Detail d ON d.masterid=m.masterid and d.DetailCategoryId=15
LEFT JOIN Detail dflt on dflt.masterid=-1 and d.DetailCategoryId=15
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  See this Fiddle with both of our solutions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90672/10 -- this is how I started before I realized it wouldn't work correctly.

Comment: @sgeddes It would if OP set the aliases right - second `left join` should read `LEFT JOIN Detail dflt on dflt.masterid = -1 and dflt.DetailCategoryId = 15` because if record is not found in `d` then `d.DetailCategoryId` will be null which cannot be matched by `default detail` row. [SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90672/21)

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović -- yep, I see what you're saying.  Also needs to add DISTINCT : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67c2f/2

Comment: @sgeddes I don't think so. There should be only one `default` record per DetailCategoryId. Otherwise OP would need additional indicator to be able to isolate `default` record.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović -- no worries, I only assumed the Detail table could have multiple rows per MasterId... Per OP "MasterId of -1 which indicate default values for each detail category" - default values -- like I said, not a big deal -- this solution works well.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT M.MasterId, M.Description, D.DetailId
    FROM Master M
      LEFT JOIN Detail D ON M.MasterId = D.MasterId AND D.DetailCategoryId = @CatId
  )
SELECT  MasterId, Description, DetailId
FROM CTE
WHERE DetailId IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT CTE.MasterId, CTE.Description, D.DetailId
FROM CTE 
  JOIN Detail D ON D.MasterId = -1 AND D.DetailCategoryId = @CatId
WHERE CTE.DetailId IS NULL
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90672/9) for testing.

Good luck.

Comment: Pretty sure this would give you both records

Comment: Edited -- see solution with Fiddle above.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

```
DECLARE @MasterID INT;
SET @MasterID=123;

SELECT  d.DetailID, d.DetailCategoryID, d.Description
FROM    Detail d
WHERE   d.MasterID=@MasterID;

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 -- If no rows then fetch default rows
BEGIN
    SELECT  d.DetailID, d.DetailCategoryID, d.Description
    FROM    Detail d
    WHERE   d.MasterID=-1;
END;
```

[@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

**Second solution:**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY x.MasterID DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM (
        SELECT  d.MasterID, d.DetailID, d.DetailCategoryID, d.Description
        FROM    Detail d
        WHERE   d.MasterID=@MasterID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  d.MasterID, d.DetailID, d.DetailCategoryID, d.Description
        FROM    Detail d
        WHERE   d.MasterID=-1
    ) x
) y
WHERE y.MasterID=-1 AND y.Rnk=1
OR y.MasterID>0;
```

Note: this last solution assumes that all `MasterID` non-default values are greater than 0 (`MasterID>0`).